# What's the difference between "when" and "while" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

What's the difference between "**when**" and "**while**" in the following context?

***Examples***:

In present progressive tense:

> I'm writing **when** I'm eating now.
>
> I'm writing **while** I'm eating now.

In present simple tense:

> I write **when** I eat.
>
> I write **while** I eat.

Answer (score 2):

"I write **when** I eat." means that whenever or every time you eat you write as well.

"I write **while** I eat." means that you write during your meal, at the same time.

I don't think the first two sentences are correct. I am writing and eating right now sounds better to me.

Comment: Thank you. Are you a native English speaker?

Comment: No I'm not. I have a degree in English though.

Comment: The second sentence in the question is grammatical—although the use of *now* at the end is very unusual and makes it sound wrong. The first sentence in the question, however, is certainly wrong—even without the use of *now*.